# Discrete Math: Multiplication Principle Word Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Assuming that there will never be more than 500 million people in the United States before the year 2050 AD, how many alphanumeric-upper digits are necessary to provide every person with a personal zip code?  (Notice that businesses and institutions are being neglected in this count.)

If the answer is 9 digits, how can I write this in the form ${n \choose x}$?

Comment: This is a [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) problem, not a combinations problem.

Comment: If I have understood the question correctly, then I have to ask: do you understand **logarithms** enough to solve for the smallest value of the positive integer $n$ such that $(36)^n \geq 500000000$?  This question assumes 36 available symbols, and that the left-most character can be zero.

Comment: @user2661923 Well I see how you got this inequality, and I used a logarithm calculator online and got 5.58951, but I'm a bit rusty on logs. How would the log equation look like to solve for n?

Comment: See my answer.  If questions, please leave comment directly following my answer and I will automatically be flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r ~=~ 500000000$.

You want the smallest positive integer $n$ such that

$$36^n \geq r.$$

Taking logarithms of both sides:

$$n \times \log ~36 \geq \log ~r \implies n \geq \frac{\log ~r}{\log ~36}.$$

By the way, this can actually be *approximately* solved without a calculator, by using logarithms, base $10$, rather than base $e$, if you happen to know that

$$\log_{10} ~2 ~\text{approximately} ~=~ 0.301
~~\text{and} ~~ \log_{10} ~3 ~\text{approximately} ~=~ 0.477.$$

Then, you have that

$$\log_{10} ~36 ~\text{approximately} ~=~ 
2 \times \left(0.301 + 0.477\right)
$$

and

$$\log_{10} r ~\text{approximately} ~=~ 
8.699.
$$

Therefore, $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that

$$n \geq \frac{8.699}{2 \times \left(0.301 + 0.477\right)}.$$